# Delete multiple posts from multiple pages facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm thinking about a scenario like this, I have multiple Facebook pages, and I have the `access_token`(s)  for each page ( with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions ), and I have a list of `post_id`(s) from each page, now I want to delete all post at once from each page. For this in graph API Facebook provides

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/546349135390552_1116689038356556
?access_token=your-access-token
```

Obviously I can call `n` number of requests to delete `n` number of posts from `n` number of pages but, Is there any way to do this in a single API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: have a look the Batch API endpoint, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Comment: You can use multiple different access tokens for individual operations, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#differentaccesstokens